# View commits without whitespace changes on GitHub

Tags: git, github, whitespace

Is there a way to display a commit on github.com without showing whitespace changes?

Is there a way to display that from console? i.e. clone and then look at commit (tree) locally ignoring all white space changes?

I use Trac extensively; I'm looking for something similar to `Ignore White space changes` (which can be found on the changeset view).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/xPaw/de6ee132a2e267ef6960: Adds a button in GitHub UI to ignore whitespace changes in commits

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Append `?w=1` to the URL on any github.com page that is showing a diff and it will ignore whitespace. See [this blog post](https://github.com/blog/967-github-secrets).

Comment: Seems like it's not working for everyone for some reason. Pity, this would have been a great feature.

Comment: I've found this works on GitHub's diff pages, but not on GitHub's blame pages

Comment: Note that if the URL already contains a question mark, you should add `&w=1` instead of `?w=1`.

Answer (score 20):

There is a trio of options that you can use at the command line (with any of git's diff commands) for this:

- `--ignore-space-at-eol` Ignore changes in whitespace at EOL.
- `-b, --ignore-space-change` Ignore changes in amount of whitespace. This ignores whitespace at line end, and considers all other sequences of one or more whitespace characters to be equivalent.
- `-w, --ignore-all-space` Ignore whitespace when comparing lines. This ignores differences even if one line has whitespace where the other line has none.

I don't believe github has implemented anything using these options.

Comment: As of https://github.com/blog/967-github-secrets -- you can Add ?w=1 to the URL to see the diff with whitespace ignored.

Comment: unfortunately, ?w=1 doesn't seem to ignore newline characters, what the damn

Answer (score 1):

Sadly the X thing is gone and alongside the previous snippet is rendered useless. Here is something that should work for now:

```
var i, e, tr, tdL, tdR, textL, textR, text = function (el) { return el.parentNode.children[2].children[1].children[0].textContent.replace(/\s/g, '').substr(1); }
for (i = 0, e = document.getElementsByClassName('gd'); i < e.length; ++i) {
    tr = e[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    if ('&nbsp;' !== tr.children[1].innerHTML) { continue; }
    tdL = tr.children[0];
    tdR = document.getElementById(tdL.id.replace(/^L(\d+)L/, 'L$1R')),
    textL = text(tdL);
    textR = text(tdR);
    if (textL === textR) { tdL.parentNode.style.display = tdR.parentNode.style.display = 'none'; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking into source HTML of commit page, I've found out that github marks pure whitespace changes with "x" CSS class... Which makes the following oneliner possible:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].hasX = function(obj) { var $this = $(obj); return ($this.find('.x').length && $this.next().find('.x').length); }; jQuery('.data tbody tr:hasX').toggle().next().toggle();
```

What it does, is runs through all rows of the commit table, and hides rows if given line and the one after that do have ".x" element in them.

Here's full JS:

```
// create new selector
jQuery.expr[':'].hasX = function(obj) {
    // cache
    var $this = $(obj);
    // whether this and next line do have '.x' element as child
    return $this.find('.x').length && $this.next().find('.x').length;
}

// select all rows and hide (ones containing "-")
jQuery('.data tbody tr:hasX').toggle()
// hide the ones after selected (ones containing "+")
    .next().toggle();
```