# How to remove white space file before commit and upload on git

Tags: github

How we can un-commit a file if there is white space change expect general change

I follow the link [Commit without whitespace changes on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449834/commit-without-whitespace-changes-on-github)

Answer (score 3):

If you already committed in your local repo, you can remove whitepaces in files of your last commit with:

```
git rebase --whitespace=fix HEAD~
```

(as mentioned in "[git remove trailing whitespace in new files before commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19151940/6309)")

Note that if you *already* pushed the bad commit on GitHub, you would need a git push --force to publish the fixed commit: that can be problematic if others have already fetched from that same GitHub repo.

---

If you don't want to apply that fix to *all* files of a commit, but only to a specific file, *before* commit, you can create a patch based on its git diff, and apply that patch with the [`git apply --whitespace=fix`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) option.

See "[`git-fix-whitespace`](https://github.com/RichardBronosky/git-fix-whitespace/blob/master/git-fix-whitespace)" by [Bruno Bronosky](https://github.com/RichardBronosky).

---

Update Oct. 2020 (five years later): you now have an alternative on GitHub side, using [GitHub Action](https://github.com/features/actions).
See "[How to avoid whitespace being committed with GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64599906/6309)".

Comment: like we have use git diff which show difference and what will we for white space if there is white space then file doesn't list else it list

Comment: @smartdeveloper if git diff shows a difference, then you can apply the git-fix-whitespace" I mentioned to fix it. Then add and commit.

Comment: git -fix -whitespace
Unknown option: -fix
usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c name=value]
           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]
           [-p|--paginate|--no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]
           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]
           <command> [<args>]

Comment: @smartdeveloper the way you would use that script (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RichardBronosky/git-fix-whitespace/master/git-fix-whitespace) is by copying it in a folder referenced by your PATH, then add your files to the index (with their whitespace issue), and call the script with `git fix-whitespace --cached` (note the space between `git` and `fix-whitespace`)

Comment: abc@abc:/var/www/zends$ git fix-whitespace --cached
git: 'fix-whitespace' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
pankaj@kindlebit-desktop:/var/www/zends$

Comment: @smartdeveloper that meant you didn't copy the file `git-fix-whitespace` in a folder referenced by your `$PATH`, or didn't make it executable (`chmod 755 git-fix-whitespace`.

Comment: I try this - > git rebase --whitespace=fix HEAD~
Here is message
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: white space