# How to only commit changes not containing indentation whitespace changes in Git

Tags: git, whitespace

Is there a way, short of manual changes using scripts, text editors, etc., using Git commands, to take a current set of changes that are either already in the cache, or not yet in the cache, and `git commit` *only* those lines that have changed non-whitespace characters?

A suitable answer may involve first `git commit`-ing the changes, and then using `git rebase` with various options similar in spirit to `--whitespace=fix`.

I observe that using the `git apply` options, or the associated `git rebase` options that relay to `git apply`, of `--whitespace=fix` is not the answer, because of this paragraph in the `git-apply` man-page:

```
--whitespace=<action>
    When applying a patch, detect a new or modified line that has whitespace errors. What are considered whitespace errors is controlled by
    core.whitespace configuration. By default, trailing whitespaces (including lines that solely consist of whitespaces) and a space character
    that is immediately followed by a tab character inside the initial indent of the line are considered whitespace errors.
```

I've verified this is the case with a `git rebase --whitespace-fix @~` command on commit, on `HEAD`, that has indentation whitespace changes (specifically fixing indentation that has a space followed by a TAB): The lines that did change indentation were still included.

Thus the answer to [How to remove white space file before commit and upload on git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623101/how-to-remove-white-space-file-before-commit-and-upload-on-git) is not the answer to this question, unfortunately.

The reason: I need to first do a commit that contains "real changes" that do not contain changes to indentation. At a *later* point in time, I might or might not choose to re-indent the entire file (removing embedded TABS in indentation, too) and check that in as a commit. I do **not** desire to do the re-indentation change to the file *prior* to the commit containing the "real changes".  I do **not** want to first reindent the whole file, commit that, and then subsequently apply the changes: I already know that is a workaround, but that is not my question.

(In case it matters: I'm currently using git version 2.28.0).

Comment: So to be clear, you're looking for a solution that does not involve shell scripting, or would you be okay with one that does?

Comment: @bk2204 Ok, well, only if it does not require use of `rpm`, `yum`, or `apt`. E.g. something using what is usually installed on a stock RHEL or CentOS machine. Because if we get into using tooling that is outside of Git, we have to talk about operating systems, versions, etc. etc.

Comment: This answer seem to address your request - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7149602/4158037. Please check.

Comment: @Prasanna I think that is _highly_ likely to be the answer to my question.  I will read that thoroughly. Thank you.

Comment: So https://stackoverflow.com/a/7149602/4158037 is sufficient as an answer to this one.  Perhaps it could be closed as a dup, but I'm not going to investigate how, because there is not efficient facility for indicating such by the OP.